# Plot with different x-axis labels

Tags: r

file.txt:

```
comp        col     chr pch
0.0256626   black   MT  20
0.03112212  black   MT  20
0.03295112  black   MT  20
0.03294942  black   1   20
0.02806124  black   1   20
0.03224467  black   1   20
0.03153024  black   1   20
0.0333732   black   1   20
0.03294344  black   1   20
0.02285203  black   1   20
0.03283011  black   1   20
0.0334126   blue    1   20
0.02593233  black   2   20
0.0297971   red     2   20
0.02666644  black   2   20
0.02882936  black   2   20
0.02870307  black   2   20
0.03222953  black   2   20
0.03314435  black   2   20
0.03346504  black   2   20
0.03131088  black   2   20
0.02862249  black   3   20
0.02477703  black   3   20
0.02890272  black   3   20
0.02822164  black   3   20
0.02886585  black   3   20
0.02753727  black   3   20
0.03026732  black   3   20
0.02918728  black   4   20
0.03045214  black   4   20


plot(file$comp, ylim = c(0,0.2), col=file$col,
         cex=file$cex, pch = file$pch, xaxt="n")
```

Instead of getting a graph in which the `X axis` is set to the number of observations `(1:30)`, I want suppress that `(xaxt="n")` and label the axis according to the column heading `chr`. Thus, 3 observations under `MT`, 9 under `"1"`, and so on.

I'm sure there's a simple solution, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axis`

```
  df <- data.frame(

  comp = c(0.0256626, 0.03112212, 0.03295112, 0.03294942, 0.02806124,
            0.03224467, 0.03153024, 0.0333732,0.03294344, 0.02285203,
            0.03283011, 0.0334126, 0.02593233, 0.0297971, 0.02666644,
            0.02882936, 0.02870307, 0.03222953, 0.03314435, 0.03346504,
            0.03131088, 0.02862249, 0.02477703, 0.02890272, 0.02822164, 
            0.02886585, 0.02753727, 0.03026732, 0.02918728, 0.03045214 ), 
  col = c(rep("black", 11), "blue", "black", "red", rep("black", 16)),
  chr = c(rep("MT", 3), rep("1", 9), rep("2", 9), rep("3", 7), rep("4",2)),
  pch = c(20))

plot(df$comp, ylim = c(0,0.2), col=df$col,
     cex=df$cex, pch = df$pch, xaxt="n")

axis(1, at =1:nrow(df), labels = df$chr)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to count how many observations fall within each "chr" and the colour? My file has thousands of rows

Comment: I don't understand. There is no counting within each "chr". All the work is done in the command `axis(1, at =1:nrow(df), labels = df$chr)`. If you are referring to `rep`. This command is just to recreate your example. It repeats the element (first argument) as many time as indicated in 2nd argument